# resurrected users in google-fabric

Tags: google-fabric, fabric.io

I have searched the fabric documentation and "googled" this question, but have been unable to find an answer. Does anyone know what defines a resurrected user in the Google-Fabric platform?

This user is identified on the RETENTION tab, lower section of the 3rd graphic down next to NEW users.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Mike from Fabric here. A Resurrected User is someone who was active previously in the app, but has **not** been active in the most recent 7 days. When they start using the app again, they are considered to be resurrected.